# Create a list by doing operations which depend on multiple indices - python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I am looking for a faster and more *pythonic* way to create a list whose elements depend on multiple indices from another list. An example of the code:

```
import numpy as np
xrandomsorted = np.sort(np.random.randn(1000000)) #input which needs to be used
Npts = int(len(xrandomsorted)/3)

#Part to be optimised begins here
final_list = np.zeros(Npts)

for i in range(Npts): 
    xval = 12 - 3*xrandomsorted[i] + 7*xrandomsorted[2*i] - xrandomsorted[3*i]
    final_list[i] = xval
```

I have found this solution to be marginally faster (though I still think there may be better solutions!):

```
list1 = xrandomsorted[0:Npts]
list2 = xrandomsorted[::2][0:Npts]
list3 = xrandomsorted[::3][0:Npts]

final_list = []

for value1, value2, value3 in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    xval = 12 - 3*value1 + 7*value2 -value3
    final_list.append(xval)
```

Is there any other way to make the code faster without using numba/cython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NumPy slicing for a vectorised solution:

```
n = Npts
A = xrandomsorted
res = 12 - 3*A[:n] + 7*A[:n*2:2] - A[:n*3:3]
```

The syntax is akin to Python `list` slicing syntax, i.e. `arr[start : stop : step]`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `itemgetter`?:

```
for i in range(Npts): 
    a,b,c = operator.itemgetter(i,2*i,3*1)(xrandomsorted)
    xval = 12 - 3*a + 7*b - c
    final_list[i] = xval
```

It is a powerful tool although don't know about the fastness.